# Поясніть, будь ласка, значення слова "розбруньковуватися"

Tags: значення-слів

Поясніть, будь ласка, значення слова *"розбруньковуватися"*.

Comment: Вітаємо на Ukrainian Language.SE. Будь ласка, наступного разу додайте до свого запитання, що ви шукали і яких висновків ви вже дійшли. Почитайте про наші [критерії](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/Хороші-питання-і-хороші-відповіді-good-questions-and-good-answers), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші питання. Ви завжди можете виправити своє питання або відповідь за допомогою посилання edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[СУМ-11:](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozbrunjkovuvatysja)

> РОЗБРУНЬКО́ВУВАТИСЯ, ується, недок., РОЗБРУ́НЬКНУТИСЯ, неться і
>   РОЗБРУНЬКУВА́ТИСЯ, ується, док. Виростаючи, розтулятися, розкриватися
>   (про бруньки, квіти, листя).  * Образно. Ще про віщось марила дівчина
>   — про щось хороше, хвилююче, що дедалі дужче розбруньковувалось у
>   теплих грудях (Олесь Донченко, II, 1956, 126);
>
> //  Покриватися
>   листям, квітами, сережками (про дерево). Чудесний весняний день…
>   Сонце… Ось-ось розбрунькнуться каштани… (Остап Вишня, I, 1956, 398).

Answer (score 2):

На [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/r/rozvivatisja/39-1-0-14021) пишуть,що:

> синонім до слова РОЗВИВАТИСЯ: розгортатися, розкручуватися, розмотуватися, розплітатися; П. перебувати в розвитку; (- фірму) розбудовуватися; (- дітей) РОСТИ, зростати; (- події) відбуватися; (- рух) набирати сил, міцніти; (- економіку) прогресувати, г. поступати, о. пишним цвітом процвітати; (- бруньки) **розбруньковуватися**, РОЗПУСКАТИСЯ.

Comment: Думаю, що перша половина відповіді дублює відповідь, яка була опублікована раніше, і тому варто прибрати. А от друга половина, дійсно, цікава. На жаль, ОП не вказувала контекст, тому тим, хто відповідає, доводиться вгадувати. А коли (якщо) автор виправить своє запитання, воно може інвалідувати наявні відповіді. До речі, саме з цієї причини на погані запитання не варто відповідати взагалі, а варто уточнювати, чого са́ме шукає автор.

Comment: Абсолютно погоджуюсь з Вами. Щодо першої частини відповіді, то зараз приберу. Ймовірно так вийшло, бо одночасно писали з автором попередньої відповіді, однак мені більше часу знадобилося, щоб її розширити.

Comment: Згоден, таке досить часто трапляється. :)